# Filter out an attribute on Ruby object created from a Gem in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a gem that acts as a wrapper for a 3rd party API. I now reference that gem in my main rails project. I have a standard pattern of:

`TheGem::Client.new(api_key: current_user.account.token)`

I can use `encrypts :token` when handling the sensitive token attribute on the `Account` model.

However, the gem creates a client and a custom class:

`#<TheGem::Client:0x0000000112505628 @adapter=:net_http, @api_key="197a.....7uw">`

The same api_key here is listed as an attribute of this custom object created by the gem but I can't make use of built in ActiveRecord encryption (as far as I know) when creating the object. Feels like I'm negating the security effort of `encrypts :token` but I see this as a pretty common strategy across gems I use. Maybe I'm missing something obvious here.

What is the strategy for handling and filtering out a sensitive attribute on a custom object created from a gem in the same way as `encrypts :token`?

Comment: As far as I know the `encrypts` directive is only there to encrypt the DB, not model attributes, or API parameters. So I don't see any problem with what is going on here. Unless I misunderstood what you really want to accomplish? If you want to remove the `api_key` attribute from the console output (is that what you are asking?), then you would need to look to modify the `inspect` method of your object.

Comment: Yeah, the original intent of the question was to treat this attribute with the same level of sensitivity as `encrypts` namely logging. I'll look into inspect. 

The larger question of strategy around securely handling users stored api keys is still there for me. Oauth is not possible here. I store api keys they have saved. Use `encrypts` for the `api_key` at the DB level. I then create the custom objects at runtime of the requests. 

Is that the correct approach?

Comment: Sounds good to me. Saved keys are encrypted, and only unencrypted keys are used in memory. This is fine. Just check that you are not accidentally logging any keys from your own objects to disk. Otherwise seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for the extra eyes and chatting it out. Added the `inspect` method to the gem to mimic other the filtered pattern in rails logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on guidance from @casper I added the following to my gem.

```
def inspect
  "<TheGem::Client @adapter=#{@adapter}, @api_key="[FILTERED]">"
end
```